# Search bar for multiple columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using a textbox to search a datagridview. But it only searches one column. I'd like to use it to search other columns as well. The code i'm currently using for the searchbar is:

```
private void autoZoeken_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("kenteken LIKE '%{0}%'", autoZoeken_txt.Text);
    autoView_dgv.DataSource = DV;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to modify the code to leverage the `OR`:

```
private void autoZoeken_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format(
        "kenteken LIKE '%{0}%' OR field2 LIKE '%{0}%'", autoZoeken_txt.Text);
    autoView_dgv.DataSource = DV;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: More information about expressions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx